# Removing the space beetwen the div and the table using css

Tags: html, css

the code i've writed so far:

```
<div>
<h1>Classification <br>of raid levels</h1>
</div>
<table>
...
</table>
```

there is space between the div and the table, and i would like to remove it using the css, is it possible?

that's how it comes now:

[image]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: I think your header has margin set to something. Try set `h1{margin: 0}` in css.

Answer (score 1):

Set `margin: 0` on h1

```css
h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
<h1>Classification <br>of raid levels</h1>
</div>
<table>
...
</table>
```

Comment: thanks for the advice, it worked

Answer (score 1):

Add margin-bottom:0; to the div or maybe a margin-top on the table? Have to use your dev tools and see where it is.